# Tripur madhanakshi Sadhana

Tags: bala-tripura-sundari

I want to do tripur madhanakshi mantra sadhana. Who is the deity related to this mantra? What are the rules and regulations to be followed for this sadhana? How many times and how many days does this sadhana needs to be performed?

Comment: Dasa Mahavidya Upasana should not be done without guidance....Because if things go wrong during sadhana you need someone to consult who can advice you on how to minimize repercussions